# Why the size of file with cropped image is the same as of initial one?

Tags: pdf, crop, inkscape

I have scanned my copybook and want to crop out extra white regions with Inkscape.

To achieve this, I import initial image (PDF) to Inkscape, draw appropriate rectangle, and use Object->Clip->Set to cut out needed region. Then I resize page to drawing and save obtained page as new PDF file through File->Save a Copy.

I expected that the size of the new PDF file (with cropped image) will be less than the size of the initial PDF (with image without crop), but they are the same.

What is the reason of this and may it be worked around?

I use Inkscape 0.91 at Linux Mint 18.2.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the original image is still there, fully intact and with all its contents. The cropping rectangle are just instructions to the PDF viewer to crop out those regions when rendering the image.

However in Inkscape you can bake the crop rectangles and when exporting to PDF "apply raster effects" which should actually alter the contained image(s).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Before exporting to PDF I have applied Filters->Pixel tools->Pixellize to the image. It really decreased size of the output PDF from 4.4 MB to 1.9 MB. Thank you!

Comment: To be honest, for cropping raster images, I would suggest to use the appropriate type of computer program - a raster image editor, like Gimp, or even some simple photo app can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Inkscape 1.2, you can convert the clipped image into a bitmap by following the below:

1. Select the clipped image
2. Choose Edit menu -> Make a Bitmap copy (or use the shortcut Alt+B)

A bitmap image copy will now be inserted into the page. You may delete the original image or move it outside the page, just in case. If you now export the page as a PDF, it should no longer have the original full image in its file data, the file size must be much smaller.

The image resolution of the copied bitmap can be improved by setting an appropriate dpi value for "Resolution for Create Bitmap Copy" setting found in Edit -> Preferences -> Imported Images, before performing the Bitmap copy operation.

The alternative solutions suggested earlier by using the pixelize filter function and then applying raster effects over the filter during PDF export didn't give a good resolution for me in cases where the image was rescaled to smaller dimensions.